# How are strings coerced into uint?

Tags: solidity

I executed a call `checkConstant("ein schnitzel")` on the following contract, and it worked. Obviously, type coercion but the documentation doesn't tell. How does this happen in detail?

```
contract X{
uint a=12+1 ether;

function checkConstant(uint conversionRate) constant returns(uint integer, uint decimal){

    integer= a / conversionRate;
    decimal= a % conversionRate;
}

}
```

Output:

```
Value: 
"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000cac53f2b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e88c37f"
Decoded: 
uint256 integer: 3401924395
uint256 decimal: 243843967
```

Comment: What generates the 'output' you quoted? Clearly not just the code you pasted.